# Parse TXT File Into 2D String Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing, text

I am looking for a way to parse a text file I have into a 2D String array with 9 rows and 7 columns. Every Pip should be another column and every Enter should be another row. `100|What color is the sky?|Blue,Red,Green,Orange|Blue`

Here is the code I have so far but I don't know how to correctly parse it.

```
private void loadQuestions()
    {
        string line;
        string[,] sQuestionArray = new string[9, 7];
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("questions.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

        }
        file.Close();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say 7 columns, do you mean that commas should also be treated as separate columns as well?  IE - Row 1 should be 100 - What color is the sky? - Blue - Red - Green - Orange - Blue ?

Comment: Given your example, how would you expect your array to be structured? (example)

Comment: Array should be like [100,What color is the sky,Blue,Red,Green,Orange,Blue] then there are 9 rows similar to that but the contents of each column vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `string[][]` instead of `string[,]` then you can do

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("questions.txt");
string[][] result = lines.Select(l => l.Split(new []{'|', ','})).ToArray();
```

Comment: Just trying to figure out how yours works. I assume it stores the information in `string [][] result` but how do I call the values? I tried calling `result[1][1];` but I just get an error "Index was outside bounds of the array."

Comment: @Cistoran can you post a few lines of sample data? with just one line, you could try `result[0][1]` I guess.

Comment: Oh that works excellent, forgot that arrays start at 0 and not 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Ex: `var splitLine=line.Split(new[] {',', '|'});`